# OCaml - Rejecting negative numbers

Tags: while-loop, ocaml

I want to create a program that sums two ints. However, they must be both positive.
I wanted to write something like this:

```
let n = read_int ()

while n<=0 do
    let n = read_int ()
    done
```

So it would read the number again, until it checks that it's positive.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Either use a reference and a while loop (imperative style) or a recursive function.

Comment: Or, use `abs` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the other answers, a recursive function that would do the job would look like

```
let rec read_next_non_negative_int () =
  let n = read_int () in
  if n < 0 then
    read_next_non_negative_int ()
  else
    n
```

Let's figure out how it works. It reads an integer `n`. If `n` is negative, that's no good, so we try the whole thing again. However otherwise, we have found a non-negative `n` so we just return it.

This is a very basic example of a recursive function. Recursive functions always have :

- A call to the function itself inside their own definition. Here, it's in the `then` clause of our test.
- An `recursion termination`, which is basically a `return` statement in many languages, but in OCaml you don't explicitly writes `return`. Here, it's the `n` in the `else` statement.

Without a self-call, the function wouldn't be recursive, and without recursion termination, it would loop forever. So when trying to write a recursive function, always think "What's the scenario in which there is no need to call the function again", and write that as your recursion termination(s). Then think "And when is it that I need to call my function again, and with which parameter", and write the self-call(s).

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't syntactically valid, but even if it were valid it's based on the idea of changing the value of a variable, which isn't possible in OCaml.

In imperative programming you can change the value of `n` until it looks like what you want. However, OCaml is a functional language and its variables are bound to one value permanently.

The `n` that appears in `while n < = ...` is not the same `n` that appears in `let n = read_int ()`. The keyword `let` introduces a new local variable.

It might help to imagine writing a recursive function that returns the next non-negative value that it reads in using `read_int`. If it doesn't get a good value, it can call itself recursively.